# Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology Bott, Tu, Definitions

Tags: algebraic-topology

Is this book outdated? Because a couple of the terms I came across seemed weird.

e.g. On page 16 at the bottom it says *differential complex* for something that should be called *cochain complex*

On page 21 at the top it says *trivialization* for something I know as *coordinate map or coordinate system*

Comment: No, it is not outdated. It sounds like you've done a fine job of understanding terms you haven't encountered before, so you ought to get a lot of that book.

Comment: @Lee Mosher sorry what? Do I have the definitions wrong? A lot of what book? Did you mean a lot out of that book?

Comment: Sorry for mistyping: "you ought to get a lot OUT of that book".

Comment: @Lee Mosher ok thanks. But is the author's definitions still correct? Do we still call those that now?

Comment: Let me rewrite my first comment with more words. If you understand what a cochain complex is from other sources such as an algebraic topology textbook, and if you understand the authors' definition of a differential complex in the book you are referring to in your post, and if you can deduce the logical relationship between a cochain complex and a differential complex, then it seems to me that you have a full and complete understanding of what is going on, and that the usage of different terminologies is not confusing you. Therefore, you should be able to understand that book fully.